# Does Feast for Crows Expansion balance 4 player Game of Thrones?

Tags: expansions, game-of-thrones, balance

Feast for Crows expansion came out relatively recently for A Game of Thrones: The Board Game 2nd Edition. The core set is playable 3-6 players, however, 4 player was terribly unbalanced. The expansion makes the game only 4 player, so I was wondering if they did a good job balancing the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is certainly one of the goals of the expansion.  Whether or not it succeeds is somewhat subjective, but it currently has 23 ratings on Boardgame Geek and is averaging an 8.61 out of 10, so I would say that most people seem to think it works pretty well.